# Get data by "priority"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table for localization:

```
   Key     |         Value            |   lang
MainTitle  |  Welcome to my page      |    en
MainTitle  |  Bienvenue sur mon site  |    fr
....
```

Not all *keys* are localized yet, so the way it's currently working is.

1. Get all English rows
2. Get all localized rows (overwrite existing English ones)

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM local.strings s WHERE lang = 'en';
```

Is there a very efficient way of solving this without having to use multiple or inner queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all keys for a given language, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM local.strings s
WHERE lang = 'fr'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM local.strings s
WHERE lang = 'en' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM local.strings s2 WHERE s2.key = s.key and s2.lang = 'fr');
```

This is actually the inverse of your logic:

1. Get all localized rows.
2. Add in the English rows that don't match.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `key`
     , COALESCE(loc.value,en.value) value
     , COALESCE(loc.lang,en.lang) lang 
  FROM strings en 
  LEFT 
  JOIN strings loc 
    ON loc.key = en.key 
   AND loc.lang <> en.lang -- or maybe "AND loc.lang = 'fr'" 
 WHERE en.lang = 'en';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @lang = "fr"; # You can write this DIRECTY in the query. This was just for testing
select * from (SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY CASE WHEN `lang` LIKE @lang THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as tmp group by `key`;
```

The test-table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `key` text,
  `value` text,
  `lang` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The test-data:

```
MainTitle   Welcome to my page  en
MainTitle   Bienvenue sur mon site  fr
SubTitle    Hello   en
SubTitle    123 fr
Text1   Cookie  en
Text1   Keks    de
```

Result:

```
MainTitle   Bienvenue sur mon site  fr
SubTitle    123 fr
Text1   Cookie  en
```